# using REGEX on textInput in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I can't seem to make my regex work so i think I must be doing something wrong. If anyone could help me out that would be great.

here is my regex function

```
let validatePlate = (plate) => {
  var re = /(^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}\s?[A-Z]{3}$)|(^[A-Z][0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{3}$)|(^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]$)|(^[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]{1,2}$)|(^[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{1,3}$)|(^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,4}$)|(^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,3}$)|(^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,4}$)|(^[0-9]{3}[DX]{1}[0-9]{3}$)/

    return re.test(plate);
};
```

and I use it in textInput as follows:

```
<TextInput
onChange={validatePlate}
editable={true}
}}>
Hello
</TextInput>
```

It still allows special characters, etc.

FYI: The regex is for filtering UK numberplates.

Comment: You are not returning any string, you are returning the validation result, true or false

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried wrapping your regexp in `new RegExp()`

For example:

```
const nameRegex = new RegExp(/^[a-z ,.'-]+(\s)([a-z ,.'-])+$/i);
if (nameRegex.test(inputValue)) {
    doSomething();
}
```